# FFMPEG - Doesn't show -vstats

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I'm working with ffmpeg library and PHP. I want to get informations about **video.mp4**. 
The problem is that it works on my localhost( Windows 7/ Xampp ) , but on my linux server it doesn't... I'm able to convert videos, but I'm not able to use:

```
-vstats
```

I'm using that command:

```
$output = shell_exec( '/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i video.mp4 -vstats 2>&1');
```

And I can get proper output on localhost, but not on my server. What could be the problem here? I'm trying to finish it, but it seems it's impossible...

Best Regards,

Mateusz

Comment: `-vstats` writes encoding statistics to a log file and not to stdout. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to get duration, dimensions. Just like on my localhost, so which function should I use?

Answer (score 0):

To get information about a media file use `ffprobe`:

`ffprobe -v quiet -print_format xml -show_format -show_streams <input>`

The advantage is that it supports structured output like CSV, XML or JSON and you don't need to parse console output.